# How do I load the Paypal SDK into Silex?

Tags: php, symfony, paypal, paypal-sandbox, silex

I'm having some trouble. I'm using **Silex**, and I'm trying to load the Paypal SDK into it. I think my issue is related to *my understanding of Silex*, which is why I'm posting it here.

### My Setup

Paypal's developer website [says to add a few lines to the composer file](https://paypal.github.io/#payments) (PHP tab). So, I've done that. My new composer file looks like so (the last four entries were those suggested by Paypal):

```
{
    "require": {
        "silex/silex": "1.0.*@dev",
        "symfony/browser-kit": "2.1.*",
        "symfony/console": "2.1.*",
        "symfony/css-selector": "2.1.*",
        "symfony/dom-crawler": "2.1.*",
        "symfony/filesystem": "2.1.*",
        "symfony/finder": "2.1.*",
        "symfony/form": "2.1.*",
        "symfony/locale": "2.1.*",
        "symfony/process": "2.1.*",
        "symfony/security": "2.1.*",
        "symfony/serializer": "2.1.*",
        "symfony/translation": "2.1.*",
        "symfony/validator": "2.1.*",
        "symfony/monolog-bridge": "2.1.*",
        "symfony/twig-bridge": "2.1.*",
        "monolog/monolog": ">=1.0.0,<1.2-dev",
        "twig/twig": ">=1.2.0,<2.0-dev",
        "doctrine/dbal": ">=2.2.0,<2.4.0-dev",
        "swiftmailer/swiftmailer": "4.1.*",
        "php": ">=5.3.0",
        "ext-curl": "*",
        "ext-json": "*",
        "paypal/rest-api-sdk-php" : "0.7.*"
    }
}
```

Then, I ran composer update, and it updated everything. I checked in the vendor folder, and a paypal folder had been created and seemed to be good to go.

### The Problem

Unfortunately, even though I've done the above steps, it still isn't working. I'm following the [beginners steps outlined on Paypal's website](https://devtools-paypal.com/guide/pay_paypal/php?interactive=OFF&env=sandbox), it seems that one of the Paypal classes can't be located.

The line that causes the error is taken directly from the "beginners steps" page linked to above. For quick reference, I'll provide it below as well:

```
$cred = new OAuthTokenCredential("AQkquBDf1zctJOWGKWUEtKXm6qVhueUEMvXO_-MCI4DQQ4-LWvkDLIN2fGsd","EL1tVxAjhT7cJimnz5-Nsx9k2reTKSVfErNQF-CmrwJgxRtylkGTKlU4RvrX", $sdkConfig);
```

Unfortunately that line causes an error that says:

```
Fatal error: Class 'OAuthTokenCredential' not found in ...
```

### Summed up...

The problem seems to be that Silex isn't loading--or making available--the class **OAuthTokenCredential**. What do I do?

Comment: did you add the paypal directory to autoload?

Comment: did you add your 'use' statement to include the class in the file that you are using it in?  I'm not sure what the namespace is for the class.  Look up the namespace and add your use statement.  something like `use Paypal\Name\Space\OAuthTokenCredential.php`

Comment: @LaurynasMališauskas Hmm, I was under the impression that composer would take care of all of the autoload stuff. All I've done is what I've listed in my post. Am I missing something?

Comment: @user2930475, how do I find out for sure what the namespace is?

Comment: ignore my comment. you are right :) and you can find out your needed namespace by opening the needed class file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks [Laurynas Mališauskas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1512759/laurynas-malisauskas) and [user2930475](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2930475/user2930475) for this answer (in the comments of my post).

Looks like I had neglected to put a line such as:

```
use PayPal\Auth;
```

in my app.php file.

Once added, I also needed to change my new class line to this:

```
$cred = new PayPal\Auth\OAuthTokenCredential("AQkquBDf1zctJOWGKWUEtKXm6qVhueUEMvXO_-MCI4DQQ4-LWvkDLIN2fGsd","EL1tVxAjhT7cJimnz5-Nsx9k2reTKSVfErNQF-CmrwJgxRtylkGTKlU4RvrX", $sdkConfig);
```

---

Note that I have all of my controllers actually in the app.php file.

Comment: +1 and thank you, it helped me alot I was running in same situation

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you don't need to add anything to app.php at all.  Just do this:

```
use PayPal\Auth\OAuthTokenCredential.php;

class YourController{
    public function myAction(){
        // ...
        $cred = new OAuthTokenCredential("AQkquB...","EL1tVx...", $sdkConfig);
        // ...
    }
}
```

You should never need to modify app.php just to use a class.

Comment: Actually, in my case since my app is tiny, I'm using Silex's optional "everything in the app.php file" micro-framework approach. I'm not using any external controllers. But your approach would definitely make more sense if I had external controllers.